# Links para Tabs em Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Estou com uns problemas no [seguinte exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/9nd4j/1724/).

Pretendo adicionar Links de outra página, com href. Quando clicasse nesses links, abria automáticamente a TAB, é possível?

Primeira página onde tenho links

```
<a href="www.site.com/?page=about#tab1">TAB1</a>
    <a href="www.site.com/?page=about#tab2">TAB2</a>
```

Segunda página, onde tenho as tabs com o meu código.

```
  Licenciaturas
<ul class="navi">
    <li><a class="menu2" href="#tab1">Eng Inf</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu3" href="#tab2">Eng Quimic</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu4" href="#tab3">Eng Civil</a></li>
</ul>
<br><br>
 Mestrados
<ul class="navi">
    <li><a class="menu2" href="#tab10">Mestrado 1</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu3" href="#tab11">Mestrado 2</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu4" href="#tab12">Mestrado 3</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu5" href="#tab13">Mestrado 4</a></li>          
    <li><a class="menu6" href="#tab14">Mestrado 5</a></li>
</ul>

<div id='tab1'>
   TEXTO LICENCIATURA 1
</div>
 <div id='tab2'>
   TEXTO LICENCIATURA 2
</div>
 <div id='tab10'>
   TEXTO Mestrado 1
</div>
 <div id='tab11'>
   TEXTO Mestrado 2
</div>

$('ul.prov').on('click', 'a', function (e) {
    //Change content displayed
    $($("ul.prov a.active")[0].hash).hide();      
    $(this.hash).show();

    //Change active item
    $("ul.prov a.active").removeClass("active");    
    $(this).addClass("active");  

    e.preventDefault();
});

//Hide all content divs except first one
$("ul.prov a").each(function(index){
    if(index != 0)
        $(this.hash).hide();
    else
        $(this).addClass("active");
});

$('a').click(function(){
   $("#tabs").tabs("option", "active", parseInt(this.id));
});
```

Comment: Queres que nessa Tab seja carregada o conteúdo de outra página web, é isso?

Comment: Defina "abrir a tab".

Comment: Eu queria, que através de uma newsletter, ou outra página do site abrisse diretamente aquela TAB

Comment: Ou por exemplo tenho 2 paginas web. Uma com tabs, e textos referentes a cada tab. E uma home page, onde quero criar um link, para abrir um conteudo específico de uma das tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já que está utilizando o jQuery, você pode utilizar o [Tabs do jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/). Ele é bem simples de usar e já vem com vários eventos implementados.

Comment: Obrigado, É uma alternativa, mas já gastei horas a aplicar o outro e manipular o CSS que pensei que fosse simples aplicar um link